# How to ignore duplicate message from aws SNS. After that how to test duplicate message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, duplicates, amazon-sqs

I would like to handle message from SNS that through SQS in lambda handler.

I have to check if the message is duplicate or not, because SNS,SQS is not FIFO.

Now I think to mange messageId with dynamoDB to use ConsistentRead function. If I can ConsistentRead from dynamoDB, then I ignore that message.

Is that reasonable way to ignore message?
If you know another way, please teach me.

And, in case I can ignore the duplicate message, how to test that?

thank you for reading!

Comment: You have to store your messages in e.g. dynamodb and always check if a new message is a duplicate of that stored in the db.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I agree with you. so how to test that?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Just use SNS FIFO topics and SQS FIFO queues for message ordering and deduplication.

Answer (score 0):

How to test for message duplicates depends on how are you going to define what duplicates are. In most general case, entire message body must match exactly to be considered a duplicate. In such a case you can **calculate** `md5` or `sha1` hashe of your the message body to store in your DynamoDB table.

Also you can setup a **time window** for two messages to be considered as a duplicate. For example, a message is a duplicate only if the same message was submitted within last 1 hour or 1 day. In such a case you can add **TTL** to your DynamoDB to automatically remove messages that are older then TTL.

Comment: Do I have to check the body? Is checking messageId is not enough? messageId  is not unique?

Comment: @kiitosu Its up to you and your requirements how you define duplicates. Two messages with different messageId can have same body. No one can answer this. Only you know what is your use case.

Comment: OK! thanks! now I understand what you are saying. So, if I define, duplicates is 
 duplication of messageId, same body is OK. I have only to check messegeId to check duplication? And, if so, I think messageId is unique id created by sns, so I cant chage it. Are there any way to send message with same messageId?

Comment: @kiitosu messageid is set by aws, so it will always be unique.

Comment: I think sometime sns send more than once, and at that time messageid is same. Its not correct? messageid is always be unique?